# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes'

Tags: python, pywin32

**ModuleNotFoundError:** No module named `'pywintypes'`

I am running Windows 10 Pro 64-bits

```
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:04:37) [MSC v.1929 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import pywintypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywintypes'
>>> import win32gui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32gui'
```

---

I have installed the binaries from https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases

Both `pywin32-301.win32-py3.9.exe` and `pywin32-300.win32-py3.9.exe`

---

I have tried using the following commands

`pip install win32gui`

`pip install pywin32`

`pip install pypiwin32`

Since I need pywin32-300

`pip install pywin32==300`

All with every available options like `-U`, `--force-reinstall` and `--no-cache-dir`

```
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (300)
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (223)
```

---

I ran the `pywin32_postinstall.py` script several times

Here are the results from the `-install` function

```
Parsed arguments are: Namespace(install=True, remove=False, wait=None, silent=False, quiet=False, destination='C:\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages')
Copied pythoncom39.dll to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\pythoncom39.dll
Copied pywintypes39.dll to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\pywintypes39.dll
Registered: Python.Interpreter 
Registered: Python.Dictionary 
Registered: Python 
-> Software\Python\PythonCore\3.9\Help[None]=None
-> Software\Python\PythonCore\3.9\Help\Pythonwin Reference[None]='C:\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyWin32.chm'
Pythonwin has been registered in context menu
Shortcut for Pythonwin created
Shortcut to documentation created
The pywin32 extensions were successfully installed.
```

And the results from the `-remove` function after installation, (Ñote: this is just for the information, I haven't removed it during usage!)

```
Failed to unregister COM objects: No module named 'win32api'
Failed to unregister Pythonwin: No module named 'win32api'
Removed directory C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py
Failed to remove shortcuts: No module named 'win32api'
FAILED to remove system files: No module named 'win32api'
```

---

I have tried moving the DLL files from the roaming folder to the installation folder.

---

I have rebooted VS code and my PC several times

---

I have fully re-installed Python 3.9.6 and did all of the above again

---

**Edit:** So I found that when I do the following, it gets me past the error, but give me some followup errors

`from win32.lib import pywintypes`

```
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    from win32.lib import pywintypes
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 105, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 41, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    import _win32sysloader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_win32sysloader'
```

So I go to `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py` and change

`import _win32sysloader` to `from win32 import _win32sysloader`

And the next error:

```
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    from win32.lib import pywintypes
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 105, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 91, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    old_mod = sys.modules[modname]
KeyError: 'pywintypes'
```

But now I have to change all the library files to use this format, I don't think that's the way to go.

---

I am currently kinda clueless as to what is going on and why it doesn't work. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: No, I think I have read and tried all the related posts here on StackOverflow. This is also a different error.

Comment: Then look through the existing issues and see if any matches yours https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues